# Exporting related tables from Access to one Excel worksheet

Tags: export-to-excel

I am trying to set up an Access database and will be importing the data from Excel. We do our analysis in R and the current Excel worksheet we use is formatted and arranged to work well for exporting to R and doing analysis there.

The format is as follows:

The first 12 columns of data describe date, location and other information which then applies to the following 12 columns. The trouble is that for a single set of observations the information in the first 12 columns doesn't change from row to row but the values for the second 12 columns does change from row to row.

```
year     mm     dd   loc    start    end    obs sess test  object success

2013    5       15  park    1600    1700    MTM MTM1    1   ball    y
2013    5       15  park    1600    1700    MTM MTM1    2   stick   y
2013    5       15  park    1600    1700    MTM MTM1    3   rock    n
2013    5       15  park    1600    1700    MTM MTM1    4   rock    n
2013    5       15  park    1600    1700    MTM MTM1    5   stick   y
2013    5       15  park    1600    1700    MTM MTM1    6   stick   y
2013    6       24  yard    1500    1530    LFR LFR1    1   ball    n
2013    6       24  yard    1500    1530    LFR LFR1    2   stick   n
2013    6       24  yard    1500    1530    LFR LFR1    3   stick   n
2013    6       24  yard    1500    1530    LFR LFR1    4   stick   n
2013    6       24  yard    1500    1530    LFR LFR1    5   stick   y
2013    6       24  yard    1500    1530    LFR LFR1    6   rock    y
2013    6       24  yard    1500    1530    LFR LFR1    7   ball    y
```

Above is an imaginary dataset which matches the format of the real one (the real one is too wide to fit here).

Notice that the entries for `year`, `mm` (month), `dd` (day), `loc` (location), `start`, `end`, `obs` (observer), and `sess` (session) all stay the same but `test`, `object`, and `success` change from row to row for a given set of observations.

In Access I would like to use a unique_ID (primary key) to relate tables so that the information for the first 8 columns need only be entered once and have it relate to each entry for the last 3 columns. In this example then, I have one Excel worksheet that will become two related Access tables (objects).

Before converting to Access though I would like to know that I will be able to export the data back to Excel (and/or directly to a text file) so that it will look just like this again. That is, I do NOT want to export multiple tables to separate Excel worksheets. I want all Access tables within my database to be exported to just one worksheet and in the format shown above. The reason for this is that we run analysis in R based on both the session and the instance levels (called different things in the real data, but that is the idea) so it is important for the location data and result data to be associated with every row in the output file (.xls or .csv).

Is this possible?

I am mostly looking for an outline of how this might be done. Specific code is not necessary, though your personal assessment of the complexity of the potential code (given my complete and absolute ignorance of VBA) that will be required would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be Yes. I just need to create a Query which will return the data to the original form and then export that query as a table.